# Getting JQuery Dialog values to code behind problems

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui-dialog

I have a simply modal jQuery dialog popup that gathers address info that I need to pass to the code behind to save to the database after the user enters it.  I have searched hundreds of examples and am current at the below point, but it seems no matter what I do, the JSON string that is created shows "undefined" for all the fields I am attempting to pass over.  My conclusion is that the method I am using to build the JSON string in jQuery is wrong, but after trying many and various ways to do this, none of them work.  I have tried accessing the fields by id, but class and as seen below, by ID using various ways.  Here are snippets of the code.  Can anyone see where I have gone wrong?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#dialog').dialog({
            draggable: true,
            resizeable: false,
            autoOpen: false,
            height: 700,
            width: 550,
            modal: true,
            top: 0,
            left: 0,
            title: 'Edit Information',
            buttons: {
                'Save': function () {                        
                    $('#ibSaveInfo').click();
                },
                'Cancel': function () {
                    $(this).dialog('close');
                }
            }
        }).parent().css('z-index', '1005');
    });

    $(document).on("click", "#ibSaveInfo", function () {
        var inputArray = new Array;
        var idx = 0;

        inputArray[idx] = 'Address1:' + $("#dialog").find("#txtAddress1").val();

        idx++;
        inputArray[idx] = 'Address2:' + $("#txtAddress2").val();

        idx++;
        inputArray[idx] = 'city:' + $("txtcity").val();

        etc, etc

        var inputArrayList = "{ inputArray: " + JSON.stringify(inputArray) + "}";
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json",
            url: "Address.aspx/SaveInfo",
            data: inputArrayList,
            success: function (data) {
                //debugger;

                if (data.d.indexOf("Error") != -1) {
                }
                else {
                    $("#ResultLabel").show();
                    $("#ResultLabel").text("Sum of all the contents is: " + data.d);
                }
            },
            error: function (e, ts, et) {
                //debugger;
                alert(ts);
            }
        }); //ajax func end
    });

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#ibEdit").click(function (e) {
            $('#dialog').dialog('option', 'position', [e.pageX + 10, e.pageY + 10]);
            $('#dialog').dialog('open');
        });
    });


<div id="dialog" style="padding-left: 10px; padding-bottom: 15px;">
    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtAddress1" ClientIDMode="Static" />
    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtAddress2" ClientIDMode="Static" />
    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtCity" ClientIDMode="Static" />
    etc, etc
</div>
```

Comment: just noticed you're using asp textboxes. I udpated my answer down below. Asp controls change their id when the project is run, make sure to use regular textboxes if youre not accessing the values from the server side.

Answer (score 0):

I've just created a jsFiddle of your exact code:

http://jsfiddle.net/PfgQy/

It appears to be working with the exception of `city` form field because it's missing a # and it's case is incorrect (should have a capital C).

```
$("#txtCity").val();
```

If all your fields are still broken then it's something else on the page which you've not provided that is causing the issue.

Hope this helps.

Dave

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:
Just noticed you're using asp textboxes. With asp the ID of the elements changes. Try using regular `<input>`textboxes if you have no intention of accessing those values from the server.

instead of this

```
idx++;
        inputArray[idx] = 'city:' + $("txtcity").val();
```

you should just use the array.push function.

```
var inputArray = [];
inputArray.push('Address1:' + $("#txtAddress1").val());
inputArray.push('Address2:' + $("#txtAddress2").val();)
inputArray.push('city:' + $("txtcity").val());
```

also here instead of invoking a clickfunction in your code, just give it the reference to another function

```
$(function () {
        $('#dialog').dialog({
            draggable: true,
            resizeable: false,
            autoOpen: false,
            height: 700,
            width: 550,
            modal: true,
            top: 0,
            left: 0,
            title: 'Edit Information',
            buttons: {
                'Save': save(),
                'Cancel': function () {
                    $(this).dialog('close');
                }
            }
        }).parent().css('z-index', '1005');
    });

function save(){
  var inputArray = [];
  inputArray.push('Address1:' + $("#txtAddress1").val());
  inputArray.push('Address2:' + $("#txtAddress2").val());
  inputArray.push('city:' + $("#txtCity").val()); 
  var json = { "inputArray": inputArray};
        inputArrayList = JSON.stringify(json);
//ajax stuff
}
```

also you have 2 document ready functions so you could combine those.
both of these are ways of declaring a document ready.

```
$(document).ready(function(){});
$(function () {});
```

Comment: Whilst these are valid code improvement points it doesn't answer why the page is erroring.

Comment: @DaveHogan
you're right, I'm hoping that maybe one of these will fix his issue since I can't see any other problem with what he is doing.

Comment: `Just noticed you're using asp textboxes. With asp the ID of the elements changes` - That's why he has added the attribute ClientIDMode="Static"